# Is there any option to get timeout value from SSRS shared dataset

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, timeout, connection-timeout

With the reference of following link we are able to set the timeout option for a shared dataset:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/setting-time-out-values-for-report-and-shared-dataset-processing-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017.

How can we get the timeout value set for a particular dataset that exists on the server?

[image: Shared dataset properties in ssrs server]

Comment: Do you mean how do you get it from the dataset definition? Because you've already shown how to get it from the server.

Comment: Hi @DaleBurrell, Yes, I need to retrieve it from shared dataset definition.